# MutationObsrver not able to recognise changes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written a small script to identify the changes in the paragraph. I don't know why the changes are not identified by the `MutationObserver`. I want an alert to be displayed when there are some changes made to Text.

```js
$(function(){
    //Store the test paragraph node
    var test = $('#test');
    
    //Observe the paragraph
    this.observer = new MutationObserver( function(mutations) {
        alert('Paragraph changed!')
    }.bind(this));
    this.observer.observe(test.get(0), {characterData: true, childList: true});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contenteditable="true" id="editor">
<p id="test">
Edit the text! 
</p>
</div>
```

Any help or suggestions are highly appreciated, thank you very much in advance!

Comment: that is not the way to use it.

Comment: @Dontclickonmyprofile was kind enough not just to copy the fiddle's contents into your question, but to demonstrate the Stack Snippets feature. Nice one Dontclickonmyprofile.

Comment: Yes. Thanks Dontclickonmyprofile. and extremely sorry T.J. Crowder. Yes I did try to trick it by marking non-code as code.I will take care that these mistakes will not be repeated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `subtree: true` to the config (example below). This is because the character data that's changing isn't the `p` element, it's the text node *within* the `p` element.

If you were observing `test.get(0).firstChild` (the `p` element's initial child text node) instead, then you'd get the notification without the `subtree` flag — but of course, you wouldn't get notifications from, say, an `em` element within the `p`. So adding `subtree` is probably your best bet.

**Corrected example**:

```js
$(function(){
    //Store the test paragraph node
    var test = $('#test');
    
    //Observe the paragraph
    this.observer = new MutationObserver( function(mutations) {
        alert('Paragraph changed!')
    }.bind(this));
    this.observer.observe(test.get(0), {
        characterData: true,
        childList: true,
        subtree: true     // <===== Change is here
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contenteditable="true" id="editor">
<p id="test">
Edit the text! 
</p>
</div>
```